# Headless CMS implementation

Tags: cms

I work as a freelance web developer and build mainly brochure websites. Pretty much everything is done in WordPress. However I am now looking to go down the headless CMS route, simply because it would offer me much more flexibility for how I code the website on the front end and would also use a lot less resources. There are of course many other advantages too.

My ideal scenario would be to self-host the CMS, so that means not using a 3rd party service like Contentful, but instead something like [Directus](https://directus.io/) or [Cockpit](https://getcockpit.com/).

Both Cockpit and Directus are meant to be used standalone, and don't come as composer packages. However I want to keep the CMS in the same Git repository as the website (i.e. in its own subfolder). This way I don't have to maintain two separate repos and can use an SDK to directly include the CMS in my PHP application.

Is there anything wrong with this approach?

Answer (score 1):

Look, the idea as itself is not bad - Wordpress is even in basic package very lazy. If it hosted on shared hosting with a slow database server, than you'll get even for a site with 10 URLs pretty slow thing.

Headless CMSs, and, further, flat file based CMSs (which are thing of my choice) have all the same really important plus - they are damn fast. Until you manage some thousands URLs you are on the secure side.

But, such CMSs have all the same malus too: most of them doesn't have such extended ecosystem as WP has. Means: you don't get extensions for any possible case, and you don't get a million templates for a handful of bucks.

Hovewer, there are some new CMSs on the market, which have `some` needful extensions and some templates, which can be easy customized.

Well, yes - if sites you build

- have not much urls and
- don't need a kind of really crazy design,

so look into this direction. Your speed gain will be enormous.